# C# WPF Datagrid(DataTable) set name with a string variable

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datatable

I try to set up a Datagrid in wpf.
To fill it out I use a DataTable.
The problem is that if I want to create a new Column, I can't set the name from a List of string variables, because the Coloumn header will be wrong placed and I can't add values to the rows under the Column.
In code:

```
datatable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Test", typeof(string)));//This works

datatable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(stringlist[i], typeof(string)));//This doesn't work
```

This illustration shows the wrong placement:

[image]

Comment: I didn't get the question. Could you please precise what is the list of string variables for? why don't you use xaml binding for the list?

Comment: the list of strings is entered by the users and has each time a different length and different values. Now the list should represent the names of the columns of the datagrid. I've never took a look at xaml binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you trim any white space that the user may accidentally enter before/after the name, like this:

```
datatable.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(stringlist[i].Trim(), typeof(string)));
```